# How do I insert data based on user_id

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my Code which I need help with

I need to link user_id to user_location in second table, which I wrote out in the bottom of this question

```
<?php


/**
 * Class UserInfo
 * handles the insert information about a paricular User
 */
class UserInfo {


    private $db_connection = null;



    public $errors = array();



    public $messages = array();




    public function __construct() {

        if(isset($_POST["info"])) {
            $this->Insert();
        }   

    }




    /**
     * Handles the Insertion of user Information into database
     **/
    private function Insert() {

        if (empty($_POST['user_location'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Please fillout a location.";
        } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_location'])) {

            $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);          

            if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

                $user_id = $_SESSION['user_name'];
                $user_location = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_location']);


                $insert = "insert into users_info (user_location) values ('".$user_location."');";      
                $check_insert = $this->db_connection->query($insert);


                if ($check_insert) {
                    $this->messages[] = "Location inserted into database successfully!";
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Location could not be inserted into database.";
                }

            }   

        }

    }







}


?>









And here is my Login script






<?php


    /**
     * Class Login
     * handles the user's login and logout process
     */  
    class Login {


        /**
         * @var object The database connection
         */

        private $db_connection = null;

        /**
         * @var object Collection of error messages.
         */

        public $errors = array();

        /**
         * @var Collection of success / neutral messages
         */

        public $messages = array();




        /**
         * The function "__construct()" automatically starts whenever an object of this class is created,
         * you know, when you do $login = new Login();"
         */      
         public function __construct() {

            // create/read session
            session_start();

            // check the possible login actions:
            // if the user tried to logout ( happens when user clicks logout button )
            if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {

                $this->doLogout();
            }

            // login via post data ( if the user just submitted a login form )
            elseif (isset($_POST["login"])) {

                $this->doLoginWithPostData();
            }

         }  // end function __construct();





         /**
          * log in with post data
          */
         private function doLoginWithPostData() {

            // check login form contents
            if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {   
                $this->errors[] = "Username field is empty.";
            } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
                $this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
            } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) {


                // create a database connection, using the constants from config/db.php
                // which we loaded in index.php
                $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

                // change character set to utf8 and check it
                if(!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {

                    $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
                }


                // if no connection errors (working database connection)
                if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {


                    // escape the POST stuff
                    $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

                    // database query, getting all the info of the selected user ( allows via email address 
                    // in the username field. )
                    $sql = "select user_name, user_email, user_password_hash
                            from users
                            where user_name = '".$user_name."' or user_email = '".$user_name."';";

                    $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);


                    // if this user exists
                    if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {

                        // get result row (as an object)
                        $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();

                        // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
                        // the hash of that user's password
                        if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {

                            // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                            $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;

                        } else {
                            $this->errors[] = "Wrong password. Try again.";
                        }   
                    } else {
                        $this->errors[] = "This user does not exist.";
                    }   
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Database connection problem.";
                }

             }

        }





        /*
         * Preform the logout
         */
        public function doLogout() {

            // delete the session of the user
            $_SESSION = array();
            session_destroy();

            // return a little feeback message
            $this->messages[] = "You have been logged out.";

        }





        /**
         * simply return the current state of the user's login
         * @return boolean user's login status
         */
        public function isUserLoggedIn() {

            if (isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] == 1) {

                return true;
            }

            // default return
            return false;   
        }



    }   // ------> Close class Login



?>


Here is my Database (mySQL)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  user_password_hash varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  user_email varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  UNIQUE KEY user_name (user_name),
  UNIQUE KEY user_email (user_email)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_info (
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  user_location varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Forign constrants =   login2, users, user_id  (sorry cant post image yet, need 10 reputation)

Comment: Please post it with indentation code and use formatting editor

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: While posting the question please provide the proper indentation and explain the question briefly. if you don't provide the proper question you will not get the proper answer

Comment: sorry first time using this

Comment: what I want is when a user logs in and fills out a input box saying where their location is. I want that location to be associated with that users ID ( or session ). How do i do it so that when the user submits their location it directly inserts it into the user_info table WITH the user_id column from the first table associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of coding is this ? You are breaking all the concepts of OOPS.

Problem with your existing code and must be resolved first -

Class UserInfo

1. You are creating datamembers public. It is breaking the concept of data hiding. Your datamember should be assigned values through the functions .
   Instead of :
   public $errors = array();
   public $messages = array();
   use:
   private $errors = [];        PHP >=5.4
   private $messages = [];      PHP >=5.4
2. Constructors should not be used for these kind of operation.
3. Create a wrapper class for handling user Info.
4. Create a new Class that will handle all the database related queries.
5. You can extend this class into UserInfo class. This way, your code will not look beautiful but would be more scalable.
6. So I remove your construct
7. If you are using autoincrement field,it will automatically increase the id so do not use NULL for this. Insert statement should have proper mapping.
8. Please use exception handling instead using condition for errors.

Class Login

1. Again data hiding concept missing
2. Don't use session start in the constructor instead of this use session start in the very first line of your entry script.
3. remove constructor from this class because of no use.
4. change your access specifier to public for login and logout
5. Since, you have already created a class for database query handling (please create if you still not created.)
6. Session destory will kill all the sessions of your website at one go. Please be specific to the session you want to destroy.

Comment: Thank You for the feedback, but this is just a test application, and  i want to know how to get the user_id associated with the user_location from the 2nd table, and INSERT it into database.

Comment: Don't use insert but use update instead.
use the same table for storing location it would be quite faster while accessing.

Comment: ya, but its not even inserting into the database with the correct user_id. I'm just trying to insert a users location right now when the user is logged in. I want that location to be associated with the user_id in the second table. I don't know how to link them together Table wise, and Query wise.

Comment: I mean I guess I can use the same table, but I really want to know how to do it this way for future purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Number of table column and values in insert query are equal.

**For Example**

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```

So your insert query would be

```
 $insert = "insert into users_info (user_location) values ( '".$user_location."')";
```

Comment: Yes, i know how to do that, BUT what I want is when a user logs in and fills out a input box saying where their location is. I want that location to be associated with that users ID ( or session ).  How do i do it so that when the user submits their location it directly inserts it into the user_info table WITH the user_id column from the first table associated with it.